# Taking max values from array and placing into equal sized array with identical indices

Tags: arrays, numpy, max, numpy-ndarray

I have an array of wind speeds. It has 100 values.

```
wind=[2.3,3.4,4.5...]
```

etc. I am taking each batch of 10 (first 10, next 10, etc) and taking their maximum using:

```
wmax = np.maximum.reduceat(wind, np.r_[:wind.size:10])
```

I am also creating an empty array `wind2` of zeros the same size as the `wind` array (100 indices).

What is the best way to fill `wind2` with the values obtained in `wmax` but making sure that the `wmax` values fill the same exact index position where they were pulled from in `wind`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `np.repeat` with the repeating lengths same as the window sizes for each *group*. We will go for an easier route with repeating all with the same window-size and finally slicing to make it of same length as the input. Finally, to get that *masked-output*, use `np.where` -

```
np.where(np.repeat(wmax, W)[:wind.size]==wind,wind,0)
```

Comment: That fills the array but only repeats the maximums in each window size to fill it. If one window had winds [2,3,6,9,8], I would need the zero array to fill as [0,0,0,9,0].

Comment: @Jonathon What if it's `[2,9,6,9,8]`, would the result be `[0,9,0,9,0]` or `[0,9,0,0,0]` or `[0,0,0,9,0]`?

Comment: That is a good question. All my actual data is floats which would lessen the probabilty of that occurring. For the purposes of my project, though,, it would not matter where the repeats land in their respective windows.